# removing characters using regex in a list of strings

Tags: python, regex

I have a list with 2 items:

```
body = ['''Customer formerly known as ALEX tel # 123 . 123123 123
word word word word ...''', '12323']
```

I am trying to use regex to remove the whitespace and leave only words for the text in the 1st item.  I am able remove but not going through the list. I get error.

```
for j, item in enumerate(body):
    test = re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z-]+', ' ', body[0])
    item[0] = test
    print(item)
```

I would like the new list to be replaced with:

```
['''Customer formerly known as ALEX tel word word word word''', '12323']
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-107-301fe3075791> in <module>()
      6 for j, item in enumerate(body):
      7     test = re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z-]+', ' ', body[0])
----> 8     item[0] = test
      9     print(item)
     10 
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: What's wrong with the one-liner `body[0]=re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z-]+', ' ', body[0])`?

Comment: Your code simply doesn't make sense. You ignore the index provided by enumerate, and try to assign to the first character of each item in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

item is a string (think `"hello"`)

```
"hello"[2] = '5'
```

is not an allowed operation... a good method to debug this type of thing is to use the `print` (e.g.  `print item` before the error occures)

**that addresses why you got the error**, there are a few other issueus with your code however (see jonrsharps comment for example)

Comment: I think I understand, but I'm still not sure how to remove all the non alpha in the list's 1st item and return a new list with two strings that contains only alpa characters in the 1st string item?

Comment: I think I understand it now, jonshars worked, I'm a newbie so little slow: